# Is there a way to clean up the rectangular area of scanned pdf using the itext library?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

```
List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<>();
            PdfCleanUpLocation location = new PdfCleanUpLocation(pageNumber, rectangle, ColorConstants.BLACK);
            cleanUpLocations.add(location);

            PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDocument, cleanUpLocations);
            cleaner.cleanUp();
```

I'm working on the redaction and using itext library for it. I'm using the above code to clean up the redacted area. It is not working for the scanned/image pdfs.
Any idea why it is not working particularly for scanned pdfs? I'm looking for a solution that should work on all types of pdfs.

Comment: Can you share/link a pdf for which that reaction fails?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share that file its confidential. I'm not finding any sample files.

Comment: Have you tested your code on some image pdf from some open web site yet? If you get the same problem as with your file, you can simply post the link to that pdf here. If you don't find any pdf that way with the same problem, then there is something special about your pdf and we likely cannot help without it.